# Overcoming SecurityError: DOM Exception 18 in PouchDB on Mobile Chrome for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, web-sql, pouchdb

I am using PouchDB 3.2.1 on a web application targeted for Chrome on iOS. The below error also appears in PouchDB 3.2.0.

When trying to create a connection to a local database on Chrome on iOS, PouchDB uses that browser's WebSQL database. This, however, fails intermittently with SecurityError: DOM Exception 18 when running the application on both iPhone 5 and iPhone 5s. I have not been able to reproduce this error on my iPad 5 yet.

I am creating a new PouchDB database as follows:

```
var localDBName = "dbd8008497c6f368d";
self.localPouch = new PouchDB(localDBName, {size: 50});
```

I have also tried setting size to 49, 1, and 0 and not setting size at all.

Here is a stacktrace sourced from BugSnag:

```
[native code]:4232 openDatabase
http://192.168.1.144:8000/app/bower_components/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:4232:48 openDB
http://192.168.1.144:8000/app/bower_components/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:4275:18 WebSqlPouch
http://192.168.1.144:8000/app/bower_components/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:5655:40
[native code]:0 Promise
http://192.168.1.144:8000/app/bower_components/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js:5570:28 PouchDB
```

Here is the code near line 4232 of pouchdb.js:

```
var cachedDatabases = {};

var openDBFunction = (typeof navigator !== 'undefined' &&
      navigator.sqlitePlugin &&
      navigator.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase) ?
    navigator.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase.bind(navigator.sqlitePlugin) :
      (typeof sqlitePlugin !== 'undefined' && sqlitePlugin.openDatabase) ?
    sqlitePlugin.openDatabase.bind(sqlitePlugin) :
      (typeof openDatabase !== 'undefined') ?
    openDatabase :
    null;

function openDB(name, version, desc, size) {
  var db = cachedDatabases[name];
  if (!db) {
    db = cachedDatabases[name] = openDBFunction(name, version, desc, size);
  }
  return db;
}
```

Refreshing the the browser page does not fix the issue. Neither does closing the browser tab and re-opening the page. The only way I can fix the issue is by force-quitting the browser and relaunching the application. However, this is not an acceptable workaround for our users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this issue disappears in iOS 8.1.3. This has been verified on both an iPhone 6 and an iPhone 5.

Comment: It turns out that the issue was not one specific to PouchDB. This was a bug in WebKit itself: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140443

Answer (score 0):

Your error message seems to be a problem on Android devices that are pre-KitKat.

Not sure if Chromo on iOS has the same problem, but worth taking a look at the pouchdb common errors here for more info:

http://pouchdb.com/errors.html#android_pre_kitkat

Comment: Thank you, but my issue is specifically a Chrome / iOS issue.